# I can't change the color of the grids in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chartjs and I'm having problems with some properties, the page can be toggled in dark and light mode with a switch. I found how to change the color of the texts to be seen in dark mode with 'Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor' and it works fine, but when I try to change the color of the grids with 'Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color' it doesn't work, and no matter if I use 'Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.display = false' or another grid's property, the lines don't change.

[The grid does not change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikuiW.png)

I downloaded the Chart.js' js file and put it in the same folder as the project folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

The chart I am using is the same as in the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/

This is the function associated with the switch:

```
function changeTheme() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('switch');
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('data-theme', 'dark');

        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'; //This works fine
        Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'; //The line that should change the grid color

    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('data-theme', 'light');

        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'; //This works fine
        Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'; //The line that should change the grid color

    }
    Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
        instance.chart.update();
    });

    console.log(Chart);
}
```

Edit:
I checked that the gridLines.color property does exist, and changes its value, but the chart is still not affected.
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSFdk.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I've never used this lib so may be wrong, but it doesn't matter if you change the global settings after you've rendered the chart, you have to [update it](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options), you can see that you code to change the defaults works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunterberg/qrjc1w3o/15/). I don't know how to update it, so I won't post an answer. Good luck.

Comment: @Gunther It's strange, the code you put in jsfiddle works fine, but when trying to replicate it with a common function it does not. What I did was to check the theme, and once assigned, assign the color and reload the page, it is not the best, but this way it works.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your options object but then with the correct color:

```
yAxes: [{
       gridLines: {
            color: 'red'
       },
}],
 xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
            color: 'red'
      },
 }]
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/nfkwjvdq/2/

Comment: It is a possibility, my idea was not to modify the dataset of each one of the charts (because the dataset would have to be alternating between one color and another), but to use a global property when changing the theme. But if I can't find another way, I'll have to use it like this. Thanks!